# Cannot update package (apt) (Unable to locate an executable)

Tags: java, virtual-machine, sudo, apt

I tried to update my existing list of packages

```
sudo apt update
```

but got the following error message

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

What was the problem?